# In SQL Server 2008 the management studio is not opening

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I installed SQL Server 2008 in that I am not able to create tables and queries, there the SQL Server Management Studio is not there also the server name also not accepting in vb.net

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Please be specific of your problem. Post any error message that you encounter. We can't help you without further information